# Multiple Leaderboards in Mobile App with Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, leaderboard

I'm currently developing a mobile app (iOS, Android) in which I want to have multiple (one-per-level) leaderboards like in Candy Crush Saga. 
These leaderboards should show the best of the users Facebook friends for each level.

Unfortunately the Facebook Scores API only allows up to one score per application, so I won't be able to use this.

Now I'm looking for some way to store this leaderboard information and connect it to Facebook.

Is there any cost free way to accomplish this?
Can I save some small data for each user via Facebook or do I need some other service for that kind? I would just need to store an int[] (score per level) per user id.
Or are there possibly any free leaderboard services out there which would work with Facebook login (no extra login except for Facebook is required)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found a service which does exactly as asked:

**[OpenKit](http://openkit.io)**

Multiple leaderboards should be easy to integrate with this service and there is only Facebook login required for the user.

It is open source, supports Android and iOS and is free up to 150k MAU. And the pricing for more MAU is fair.